# Run a job every other monday

Tags: ruby, heroku, scheduler

I would like to use Heroku scheduler to run every OTHER Monday.  However, it only runs hourly, daily, every 10 minutes.

I read this...
[How can I schedule a 'weekly' job on Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835095/how-can-i-schedule-a-weekly-job-on-heroku)

However, I'm not sure what code can be used. I think I can figure out every Monday, but not every OTHER Monday.

thanks

Comment: check out: https://github.com/javan/whenever

Comment: Do you mean by every OTHER Monday every Monday except this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you get more complicated, I'd recommend checking out scheduling gems. If you want to stick to vanilla Ruby, look at a combination of `monday?` and `cweek`, which tells you the week number in the current year. Run your job on Mondays in even-numbered weeks.

```
date = Date.today
date.monday? && date.cweek.even?
```

Note that `cweek` can return 53, since 365 isn't divisible by 7 and it has to handle that last, partial week. The new year's first week will be 1 (it doesn't count from 0), so you have to either skip a week or do two runs in a row when Monday falls in week 53.